# Error while deploying Aion dApp through frontend : fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: aion

I was deploying my java contract to the Mastery network through the frontend by using a MERN stack app and came across the following error while compiling:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/parina/Documents/aion-counter/node_modules/aion-web3-eth/src'
```

To rectify this, I added

```
node: {
    fs: "empty"
    },
```

to my webpack.config.js file.
After this, I was successfully able to compile my project and start the server but on opening the project in the browser, the contract was not deployed and I got the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function at Contract.deploy (index.js?60f4:244) at _callee$ (Main.js?1523:40) at tryCatch (runtime.js?280d:65) at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?280d:303) at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?280d:117) at step (Main.js?1523:9) at eval (Main.js?1523:9) at new Promise (<anonymous>) at eval (Main.js?1523:9) at deploy (Main.js?1523:19)
```

After searching on various forums, I found out that fs is not supposed to be used on the frontend and I was suggested alternatives to it. But it here it is being used by the Aion node modules and not directly and therefore I can’t seem to find the way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved here:

https://github.com/aionnetwork/aion_web3/issues/78#issuecomment-513938605

Since fs cannot be used on the client-side, I shifted the deployment function in my MERN dApp on the server-side while doing the rest of the interactions on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned since, fs is a server-side module, the file can be uploaded (through react or whatever is the clientside module) to the server and executed server-side and response returned to the client.

So I would suggest to get the encoded byte code of the jar along with the deployment arguments and set the transaction data field to the encoded data.

For example, assuming you are deploying the counter sample contract(https://docs.aion.network/docs/deploy-a-contract#section-example-script):

```
let data = "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";


    const Tx = {
        from: "Your address",
        data: data,
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
        gas: 5000000,
        type: '0x2' //AVM java contract deployment
    };
```

This can be your transaction object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to ask if you are you encoding the value that is returned on using the web3.avm.contract.deploy() function? And are you passing the byte code of the jar file to this function? Can you please elaborate on how exactly did you get this encoded data?

Comment: Yes, I was. 
I used following:

```let data = web3.avm.contract.deploy("MY JAR Path").args(['int'],[3]).init();
```
to encode the the byte code of the contract jar along with the deployment argument.